# uploadSucceeded method of Upload button is being triggered twice instead once when clicking the upload button

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

Why is `uploadSucceeded` triggered twice when uploading a file in vaadin 7 and how can I avoid it?

```java
upload.addSucceededListener(new Upload.SucceededListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 177755930847373059L;

    @Override
    public void uploadSucceeded(SucceededEvent event)
    {
        // XXX does something
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you uploading 2 files?

Comment: no. one file only

Comment: which version of vaadin are you using?

Comment: vaadin 7.........

Comment: Sounds like a possible bug, but I couldn't find existing bug report for this. Can you more details? For example which specific Vaadin 7 version, which application server (and version), OS, browser etc.? Also if possible can you share a code example to reproduce the issue.